# Difference classical and statistical thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, terminology

What should I read to link between classical thermodynamics or engineerig thermodynamics and statistical mechanics?

Answer (score 1):

Older introductions to Statistical Mechanics (SM) took for granted that readers had studied Classical Thermodynamics (CT). A good example of such a Stat Mech book is T L Hill's "An Introduction to SM". The early chapters are just this: they explain the basic method of the Gibbs approach in a clear, coherent but very succinct fashion.

More recently (but still several decades ago) there were attempts to devise courses that interwove CT and SM. The 'brand leader' among textbooks that followed this approach was Reif's "Fundamentals of Statistical and Thermal Physics", but I prefer the less wordy (I almost said 'less ponderous') "Statistical Physics" of F Mandl.

A rather more recent book that I know less well is David Chandler's "An introduction to Modern statistical Mechanics". This starts with a couple of chapters on CT, and then moves on to SM. The chapters on CT don't constitute an introduction to CT, but develop some of the aspects that are going to be useful in the subsequent chapters.

Of course reviews/feedback by readers on a well-known online retailer can be invaluable...